# Save username and password in a cookie, or send info to url on click

Tags: url, authentication, autologin

### **Please note - the following post is for a demo site only. This is not a production site.**

The logic I want to perform goes like this...

1. ButtonClick
2. New window opens
3. Username/Password are already entered
4. User clicks 'Login'
5. User is now logged in.

I have tried this...

```
Username:PassWord1@university.edu/portal/server.pt
```

and this...

```
https://university.edu/portal/server.pt?userName=SomeUser&password=somePassword
```

but to no avail...

This is only for an internal company website and does not have any access to the outside world. ***Internal Demo Only***

**Edit:** I would like assistance on building a URL that has the username/password built in so I can accomplish the above logic.

Comment: So..............What would you like us to do about it?

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I'm sorry about that. Please see my edit above.